# Is it okay to ask questions related to the practices of researchers in the field?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask the questions related to the practices of researches in the field of artificial intelligence?

For example, I am facing an issue in understanding the existing codes in GitHub related to my research. It is due to several reasons including version updates, less documentation, etc., So, I have a genuine question on what other researchers in the domain do for coding. So, can I ask a question like

> Do most of the researchers of deep learning go through the existing code and understand it in detail *or* just use it as a module for their research without complete understanding?

Comment: We have had some of these questions (such as [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/23983/2444)), i.e. questions related to how AI researchers deal with certain problems, but I don't think we have clearly defined whether these questions are or not on-topic here. However, you're asking about questions that involve the implementation, so I'm not fully sure whether they should be considered on-topic. As long as the question is related to how AI researchers "do research", then I think this would fall into the "research/academia" part of the site, but I'm not sure. I will consult other moderators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do most of the researchers of deep learning go through the existing code and understand it in detail or just use it as a module for their research without complete understanding?

For such a "Do most researchers X or Y?" question, I would be a bit concerned about whether that can really be properly answered with any level of objectivity.

But if it's rephrased in a way such that it's more about *how* researchers can or cannot do something, or benefit from something or make use of something, I feel like that would be fine. For a phrasing close to what you seem to be interested in, I would think of something like:

> How can researchers make use of source code published alongside other researchers' publications?

and then in the body of the question expand on that question by explaining your personal experiences, without that context it may not be obvious still exactly what you mean. A bit further from the question you suggested, but still related, I'd think something like this would also be fine:

> Why is making source code for research papers [important OR valuable OR useful]?